# #appcelerator app developed in 5.0 and ios8.4 no longer runs on ios9.2 and appcelerator 5.1.1

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I didn't make any changes to the app, but the app started working funny on my ios device after upgrading from v8.4 to 9.1 then 9.2. So I deleted the app, rebuilt it in appcelerator 5.1.1, the latest version to support ios9.2. When I install on my device I get an error:
Couldn't find module: localeStrings for architecture arm64

I tried to run ti -64 in the project directory as was recommended elsewhere, but all that returned was Usage: `titanium <command> [options]`

Ideas anyone?

Comment: Clean your project and run again. and disable liveview

Comment: Thanks Nazir. I wasn't running live view, but clean and ran again with no luck. Also restarted Studio, cleaned project again, and ran with no improvement. I read several posts where the recommendation is "ti -64" but the there is no switch 64, so is there something else I need to configure so ti -64 works?

Comment: Did you tried running from terminal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error `Couldn't find module: localeStrings for architecture arm64` is related to LiveView. This might because of an unsupported NodeJS version (best to use 0.12 to 4.x) or because you upgraded Studio, which is where LiveView lives. After every Studio update, you need to use LiveView from there once to make sure the CLI hook is updated.

After checking all this, make sure you clean (`appc ti clean`) your project before you try again.

Comment: Interesting. The iOS simulator worked with v9.2, but my live device did not with my build. So following @Fokke's advice, I tried live view on my device, which failed, of course, but I then turned live view off, cleaned, and rebuilt, and it now works on my device again. Weird that I was REQUIRED to try live view before the error went away. Thanks